# duplicate magento extensions

Tags: magento, payment

how can i duplicate magento extensions and install them? I need to duplicate or rename in order to use them for my check out payment issue. the payment filter extensions enables to use payments for different products. In my websites there are alot of seller. So i need to duplicate the bKashhttp://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16591/ extension for my payment gateway. As it only depends only external mobile no. payment.

> In fine tell me how to duplicate an extension and install them.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- download the extension using this: http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
- extract the content
- replace the content in all files from "Bkash" to "Bkash2" in files ie: the content of

```sh
find . -type f | xargs sed -i "s/Bkash/Bkash2/g"
```

- replace all bkash to bkash2 in files

```sh
find . -type f | xargs sed -i "s/bkash/bkash2/g"
```

- rename all files and directories that contains Bkash to Bkash2

```sh
mv ./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Bkash ./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Bkash2

mv ./app/code/local/Mediasoftbd/Bkash ./app/code/local/Mediasoftbd/Bkash2

mv ./app/etc/modules/Mediasoftbd_Bkash.xml ./app/etc/modules/Mediasoftbd_Bkash2.xml
```

- rename all files and directories that contains bkash to bkash2

```sh
mv ./media/bkash ./media/bkash2

mv ./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Bkash2/bkash_instruction.phtml ./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/Bkash2/bkash2_instruction.phtml

mv ./media/bkash2/bkashlogo.jpg ./media/bkash2/bkash2logo.jpg

mv ./media/bkash2/bkash-send-money.jpg ./media/bkash2/bkash2-send-money.jpg
```

- copy/paste all the files (except package.xml) to your magento instalation directory

something like that should work, after that the new module should appear under system>configuration>advanced, and new configurations should be available under system>configuration>sales>payment methods

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxJYGRqDwGT0cDBCX09QSU8xOFU/edit

Comment: you sure? my site's live and many customers online. please tell me what can i do? there's an option in the magento connect to upload and use the extension.@useless

Comment: i didn't got the steps
replace all Bkash to Bkash2 in files
replace all bkash to bkash2 in files
rename all files and directories that contains Bkash to bkash2
rename all files and directories that contains bkash to bkash2
please be more specific and details.Thanks
didn't understand the 2 and 3 step. @useless