# Rename Magento extension

Tags: magento

I have a multistore setup where one store uses one theme and another store uses another. Both come with multiple extensions, which all work fine, except one. It's an upsell extension and both are named UpsellSlider. When I click on upsellslider in theme 2, it redirects me to the upsellslider of theme one. My guess is that's because both are named the same and one is loaded before (or after) the other and gets precedence.

My solution is the rename one of the extensions. How can I do that?

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687185/duplicate-magento-extensions

Comment: Why are you using two of the same module? If it's a multistore install, couldn't you use one, and then change the settings by website/store? Renaming an extension can be tedious, and you'll inevitably miss a few occurrences of the old name. I'd be sure before you start doing that.